# the character is moving to the wrong place even when I hard code a specific location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform, gameobject

so I am trying to make a turn based strategy game. currently I can select the character and yellow squares appear to where it can move. but when I click on a yellow square the character does not go to the square it goes somewhere else. if I use the same function to move the character to a specific spot then he goes to 15x0y. if I select him again and move to a spot 5 units are added to the x value. I don't know why this is happening. I tried a different approach that broke it even further. basically the character is not going where it is supposed to.

Attached to the yellow squares:

```
`     using System.Collections;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using UnityEngine;
     
     public class MovePlate : MonoBehaviour
     {
         GameObject controller;
         public GameObject reference = null;
         public float x;
         public float y;
         // Start is called before the first frame update
         void Start()
         {
             x = this.transform.position.x;
             y = this.transform.position.y;
             
         }
     
         // Update is called once per frame
         void Update()
         {
             
         }
     
         public void SetReference(GameObject obj)
         {
             reference = obj;
         }
         public GameObject GetReference()
         {
             return reference;
         }
         public void OnMouseOver()
         {
             if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
             {
                 reference.transform.Translate(x,y,-1);
                 reference.GetComponent<units>().selected = false;
             }
     
         }
     }
```

Attached to the character

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class units : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject Select;
     public GameObject movePlate;
     public GameObject tempselect;
     GameObject mp1;
     GameObject mp2;
     GameObject mp3;
     GameObject mp4;
     GameObject mp5;
     GameObject mp6;
     GameObject mp7;
     GameObject mp8;
 
     public int movement;
     public bool selected;
     private bool mouseover;
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         
         selected = false;
         mouseover = false;
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (selected)
         {
             for (int i = 1; i < movement + 1; i++)
             {
                 Debug.Log("Bacon");
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i < 20)
                 {
                     mp1 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp1.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp1.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i;
                     mp1.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i < 20 && this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i < 20)
                 {
                     mp2 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i, this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp2.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp2.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i;
                     mp2.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i < 20)
                 {
                     mp3 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x, this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp3.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp3.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
                     mp3.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i >= 0 && this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i < 20)
                 {
                     mp4 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i, this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp4.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp4.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i;
                     mp4.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y + i;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i >= 0)
                 {
                     mp5 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp5.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp5.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i;
                     mp5.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x + 1 < 20 && this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i >= 0)
                 {
                     mp6 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i, this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp6.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp6.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x + i;
                     mp6.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i >= 0)
                 {
                     mp7 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x, this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp7.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp7.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x;
                     mp7.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i;
                 }
                 if (this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i >= 0 && this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i >= 0)
                 {
                     mp8 = Instantiate(movePlate, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i, this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i, -2), Quaternion.identity);
                     mp8.GetComponent<MovePlate>().SetReference(this.gameObject);
                     mp8.GetComponent<MovePlate>().x = this.gameObject.transform.position.x - i;
                     mp8.GetComponent<MovePlate>().y = this.gameObject.transform.position.y - i;
                 }
 
             }
             
         }
         
         if(selected && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
         {
             
             selected = false;
         }
         if(!selected)
         {
             DestroyMovePlates();
         }
     }
 
     void OnMouseOver()
     {
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)&&!selected)
         {
             tempselect = Instantiate(Select, new Vector3(this.gameObject.transform.position.x, this.gameObject.transform.position.y, -3), Quaternion.identity);
             selected = true;
         }
     }
     public void DestroyMovePlates()
     {
         //Destroy old MovePlates
         GameObject[] movePlates = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MovePlate");
         for (int i = 0; i < movePlates.Length; i++)
         {
             Destroy(movePlates[i]); //Be careful with this function "Destroy" it is asynchronous
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Without looking at your code: Is your object a child of anything? Do you maybe have to use [localPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html)?

Comment: as far as I know it is not a child of anything. I can try localposition none the less and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!!!! In the moveplate code I changed "reference.transform.Translate(x,y,-1);" to  "reference.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(new Vector3(x, y, -1.0f), Quaternion.identity);"